# Running SQL Server CE 4 Queries with Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I have recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server Management Studio 2012, however I cannot seem to see how to execute SQL scripts (created by Entity framework) on a SQL Server CE 4.0 database. With VS2010 + SSMS 2008 the Transact-SQL editor would ask for a connection and you could browse to the object, however this option is not available in SSMS 2012.

I have tried to execute the script via the Server Explorer -> New Query window, but I get parse errors. Any clues?

Comment: You can ignore the parse errors, (or correct invalid syntax if required), or try the QL Server Compact Toolbox VS add-in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft got [rid of that](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/d2735d0d-f593-40e5-bf7a-356704c3aaee/) for SSMS 2012, and suggested to use the integrated tools in WebMatrix instead (from memory, can't find a link for that sorry).

As suggested in that [Microsoft Answers](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/d2735d0d-f593-40e5-bf7a-356704c3aaee/) post, however, you could use the [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/), it's pretty effective.

Comment: I've been using the Compact Toolbox heavily last year, so here are my 2 cents. I wasn't a big fan of SSMS, but it was way too better than SQL Server Compact Toolbox, which has more bugs and lack of basic functions. E.g. it doesn't have a button to stop running a faulty query, so it can freeze the whole Visual Studio for an hour. And there's no sign of any improvements coming soon. It's developing, but with speed of a snail. E.g. it took like a year to fix some bugs with connection managing.
But we don't have another choice. SQL CE is abandoned by MS.

Comment: Here is the link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879339%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using the SQL Server Object Explorer instead of the Server Explorer. That should allow you to do what you wish.

Comment: On this window when trying to add a new server the SSMS window appears which does not have an option for CE servers.