# Missing Sql Server Compact? Not in Sql Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-2012

I have Sql Server 2012 SP1 but I can't find how to create a sql compact server. It is not under connections like it was in sql server 2008.

Did they move it or do I have to install something else? According to web platform installer I have sql compact server 4.0 installed on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 doesn't come with Compact Edition.

I believe it comes with Visual Studio 2012 SP1, and it would be visible trough it.

Borik

[msdn article - Using SQL Server Compact (Visual Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983321.aspx)

[you can download SQL Compact Edition here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx%20as)

Comment: Why does it not come with VS 2012? Seems kind like a downgrade??

Comment: Sorry typo. I mean Sql Server 2012. It was in 2008 and now not in 2012 seems like a downgrade.

Comment: I have never seen SQL Compact to be packaged with full SQL Server.

Comment: Also if looking just to connect to SQL Compact See this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427459/running-sql-server-ce-4-queries-with-visual-studio-2012-and-sql-server-managemen?rq=1)

Comment: This is what I was following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms173009%28v=sql.105%29.aspx Like in Vs 2010 I can create the compact server file but I don't know how to add a table to it.

Comment: Ok I think I found how to create a table. Had to go to server explorer than add it as a connection(kinda weird would have thought that would be automatic)

Comment: In Visual Studio not in SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio), right?!

Comment: That is correct server explorer in VS 2010. Though I can only get Compact 4.0 in VS 2010 not 3.5 what I am looking for.