# How to connect to SQL Server CE file using SSMS

Tags: sql-server-ce, ssms, ssms-2012

I am using SSMS 2012 and trying to connect to the SDF created by Orchard.  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1072324/128217), I should be able to select **SQL Server Compact Edition** as the **Server type** when connecting my object browser, but that isn't an option.  Is there something I need to install?  Did I miss part of the install originally (when setting up SSMS)?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427459

Answer (score 34, accepted):

SQL Server Compact is no longer supported in SSMS 2012, I have a list of available tools from Microsoft and others here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html

**UPDATE: My SQL Server Compact Toolbox now supports SSMS 16 and 17**

Reference: [Discontinued Management Tools Features in SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879339%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: G'ack.  Yeah, I opened SSMS 2008 R2, and there it was.  Booo (to the missing feature in 2012).