# SQL Managment Studio connect to SQL CE

Tags: sql-server-ce, ssms

I have instalation of SQL Server 2012 developer edition with Managment studio. And my problem is that I am unable to connect, to SQL CE (*.sdf file). I do not have the option to choose the right server type in studio. Any help what is wrong ?

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio       11.0.3128.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools     11.0.3128.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.3.9600.16384
Microsoft MSXML                              3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                  9.11.9600.16384
Microsoft .NET Framework                     4.0.30319.34003
Operating System                             6.3.9600
```

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244993

Comment: And duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427459

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Discontinued Management Tools Features in SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879339.aspx)

> ### SQL Server Compact Edition
>
> The SQL Server Compact Edition code editor has been removed from SQL
>   Server Management Studio. Support for SQL Server Compact Edition has
>   also been removed from Object Explorer, Solution Explorer, and
>   Template Explorer. Use the Transact-SQL editors in Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 or Webmatrix instead.