# Can't use SQL Server CE in VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-ce

I'm developing a web application and was trying to use a local database file to store some information.  However, when I add the .sdf file, I get an error.  Below are some screenshots detailing my problem.

I've been trying to figure what's wrong for several hours.  I've seen similar issues, but have yet to find a fix.  I used to be able to use SqlServerCe connections before with .sdf files, though that was a different development environment.  I have tried reinstalling everything SQL several times, including downloading everything I could find on MSDN.  Can anyone help me out?

Below is my Solution Explorer View.  I've just added Database1.sdf to the project.

[image: Solution Explorer view.]

I get an error as soon as I add it:

[image: Error Message]

If I try to open the .sdf file, I get this error:

[image: Error Message 2]

Here is my list of references:

[image: References]

And, finally, all of the relevant SQL-related installations on my local machine:

[image: SQL Installations]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Have you tried to use SQL Server Compact Toolbox?  
  [1]: http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/. Could also be a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427459/running-sql-server-ce-4-queries-with-visual-studio-2012-and-sql-server-managemen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Compact 4.0 is supported by VS 2012, but requires the DDEX provider to be properly isntalled. Sounds like your VS install is somehow broken. You can install my Toolbox add-in, and go to the About dialog in the Toolbox to check if the DDEX provider and SQL Server CE 4.0 is properly installed.

Comment: I get an error saying that it's not installable on any products.  I'm going to try reinstalling my VS and see if that helps.

Comment: What VS edition do you have? The Toolbox requires Pro or higher.

Comment: I have Professional here at work.  You were right about the VS install being bad - after reinstalling it, everything works like a charm, including the toolbox.  It would have taken me quite a while to think of that given that it was still compiling everything else like a charm.  Thanks!