# Where does Orchard CMS create its built-in SQL Server Compact Database

Tags: orchardcms

You can configure Orchard CMS to use a built-in SQL Server Compact database.

I want to connect to, and query, this database.

Where does Orchard create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the development installation of Orchard, the CMS creates the SQL Server CE .sdf file in the `src/Orchard.Web/App_Data/sites/NameOfTheSite` directory.

You can connect to it using SQL Management Studio (up to 2012) by following these steps:

```
1. File -> Connect Object Explorer...
2. Change 'Server Type' to 'SQL Server Compact Edition'
3. Select < Browse for more...>
4. Browse to and select your .sdf file.
```

For versions of SQL Management Studio 2012 and above, a third-party tool is required.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427459/running-sql-server-ce-4-queries-with-visual-studio-2012-and-sql-server-managemen) for further details.

Comment: That's not accurate. It's created in `src/Orchard.Web/App_Data/sites/NameOfTheSite`.

Answer (score 6):

The database is created in:

```
src/Orchard.Web/App_Data/sites/YourSiteName
```

To connect to it I use the following plugin for Visual Studio:

[SQL Server /SQLite Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/)

For other ways to open SQL Compact databases see this SO question:

[How do you open an SDF file (SQL Server Compact Edition)?](/questions/1953248/how-do-you-open-an-sdf-file-sql-server-compact-edition/13630330)